# Number of steps

Tags: logic

In a shopping complex Sunita walks down an escalator moving down from the first to ground floor in 30 sec taking 6 steps for every 5 sec. On reaching the ground floor she realizes she has to go back to first floor and walks up same escalator in 50 seconds taking 2 steps every second. Find the number of steps on the escalator between the two floors.
Please help.

Comment: What have tried ? Have you gone to a mall to try if it's a realistic exercise :) ?

Comment: She takes 36 steps downward and 100 steps upward as per my calculations..

Comment: Note that on Math SE you are expected to briefly describe your thoughts or attempts to solve your question (in the question, not in the comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by calculating how many steps she takes on each journey, and then use the assumption that the speed of the escalator doesn't change between journeys. There is a slight ambiguity in the question as to whether she walks the wrong way up the escalator on one of the journeys.  However as she walks faster on the 2nd, but it takes longer, we know that she is travelling contradirectionally on that journey.

30 seconds comprises 6 sets of 5 seconds, and the question says she takes 6 steps during each 5 second period going down, so she takes 36 steps going down.

By the same method, she takes 100 steps going up.

The distance covered, being the same on each journey is the sum of the distance she walks and the distance the escalator carries her.  If $s$ is the length of a step, $v$ is the velocity of the escalator and $d$ is the length of the escalator then:

$36s + 30v = d$

$100s - 50v = d$

substitute for $d=d$ to find: $v=4s/5$

Substituting $v$ back into the two equations above gives $d=60s$ so there are 60 steps.

A simple intuitive check is that the answer should be between 36 and 100, which it is.